# Deleting X percentage of a file's data? (partial nullifying of a file)

Tags: files

Is there a way to delete only up to 75% of a file so that only the last (or first) 25% of it will stay in the file?

I can nullify a whole file with `cat /dev/null > /var/mail/root` but in this case I need to delete (nullify) only up to 75% of that file.

Is there a way with Bash? All docs I found talked about 100% nullification with the command above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To truncate a file at 75%, with GNU `truncate`, you could do:

```
size=$(wc -c < "$file") &&
  truncate -s "$((size * 75 / 100))" -- "$file"
```

With `ksh93`:

```
<>; $file >#((EOF * 75 / 100))
```

To remove a leading part, generally, you need to rewrite the content of the file. You could do it by writing the file over itself in `ksh93` with:

```
command /opt/ast/bin/cat < $file <#((EOF * 25 / 100)) <>; $file
```

(here using `ksh93`'s builtin `cat` command as some other `cat` implementations like GNU `cat` will refuse to work if their stdout refers to the same file as their stdin).

Or use `perl`:

```
perl -pe '
  BEGIN{
    seek(STDIN,0,2) or die$!;
    seek(STDIN,tell(STDIN)*75/100,0) or die$!;
    $/ = \65536
  }
  END{truncate STDOUT, tell STDOUT}' < "$file" 1<> "$file"
```

On Linux and on some file systems, you can remove parts of a file other than at the end without rewriting it, but only in multiples of the file system's block size. For large files, that may be good enough:

```
block_size=$(stat -Lc %o -- "$file") &&
  size=$(wc -c < "$file") &&
  fallocate -cl "$((size * 25 / 100 / block_size * block_size)) -- "$file"
```